# yarn nodemanager has high usage but the contents in directory don't reconcile with disk usage

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

This issue raised my attention because many of the jobs in our spark cluster failed recently. and their logs show "Container released on a *lost* node" message before the jobs fail.
When checking the nodes where the lost executors happen, high space usage in yarn nodemanager catches my attention. (all the tests below are done on one spark node) E.g,

```
df -h | grep /hadoop/yarn/nm-local
```

tells me that directory's usage is 800G (75% of total available space).
From my understanding, that directory is for shuffle space for spark cluster. Its space usage should be released once jobs are finished. But even when there's no jobs running in the cluster, its usage is still very high.
When probing which files cause the high usage, strange thing happens:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /hadoop/yarn/nm-local
```

tells me all the files only add up to 80G. apparently 800G doesn't reconcile with 80G. One theory to explain that is, du doesn't include the deleting files or deleted files still being used by running process. So I checked all the running process associated with that directory:

```
lsof | grep "/hadoop/yarn/nm-local"
```

But all the files used by current running process don’t add up to 800GB, not even close. Can you please help me understand where that discrepancy comes from?

Comment: Update: tried different parameter for yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms and restarted yarn, but the space usage level didn't change.

Comment: Update: Issue solved after rebooting the nodes. disk usage drops from 75%+ to 5%

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the [localizer Cache.](https://blog.cloudera.com/resource-localization-in-yarn-deep-dive/).

Those files are cleaned up periodically by yarn. ([`yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml))

If you are seeing issues when there is a discrepancy between the two you may want to decrease your clean up interval. That may or may not help, because the issue may be that you have a lot of file writing contention. (The cause of most performance issues.)

You may wish to consider the following options:

- Change `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs` to write to it's own isolated drive(Contention free drive)
- Add an additional drive(s) to the localizer to decrease contention (It's a good practice to use several drives not 1 drive)
- add threads/RAM to the localizer (Will only help if the write/read isn't an issue, **will actually make things worse if disk contention is the source of the issue**. Which is why I'm covering it.)

Comment: thanks for your reply! we have isolated drive (1 drive in each node) for yarn localizer cache, and it's HDD drive.
I'm also toggling the "interval-ms" config to see if that helps reduce the high usage in cache.